# sparse matrix of ones (not zeroes)

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I'd like to change my matrix that contains lots of ones into a sparse matrix. Is there a programmatic solution to this?

I would like to avoid converting 1's to a 0 and vice-versa, because this would make things more complicated than they should be (then I would need to put in complicated conversion steps).

```
data <- rnorm(1e6)
zero_index <- sample(1e6)[1:9e5]
data[zero_index] <- 1


Matrix::Matrix(as.matrix(data, sparse = TRUE))
```

Comment: Can you give an example? I'm confused.

Comment: added an example (which doesn't work..)

Comment: I don't think this is really possible (without making up your own "sparse-1-matrix representation" machinery.  Can you give a slightly broader context? What do you want to be able to do with these matrices?

Comment: It's just that I have a large matrix that contains a lot of 1's and want to reduce memory footprint. I was hoping the sparse matrix machinery would have some argument to say which value to make sparse :). Thanks! I will try to do it another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible without coding it yourself (i.e., writing functions to convert dense matrices to and from one of the common sparse-matrix representations, e.g. [compressed sparse column](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_column_(CSC_or_CCS))). Most existing sparse-matrix representations are heavily optimized to assume that the 'ignorable' elements are zero, because this is overwhelmingly the most common use case in scientific computation.

I was going to say that you could adapt the code in the `Matrix` package, but this conversion code is deeply buried in C code and calls CHOLMOD routines ...) One of the other sparse-matrix packages, e.g. the `spam` package, might be a better starting point.